# Multiple script hyperlinks not loading in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, vbscript, hyperlink

I've set up my layer to use hyperlinks based on a script.  When I use the Hyperlink tool and click on a link, often times it loads just fine.

[image]

The problem I have is when there are multiple points on top of each other, each with their own hyperlinks.  A window opens that allows me to select the hyperlink I'd like to use.  The problem is, I can't seem to activate the hyperlink.

Note that these links are used by a script hyperlink.  That's why they aren't websites or document paths.

I've tried selecting the link, and clicking "Jump".  I've tried double-clicking the link.  I tried pressing "Enter" on the keyboard.  I tried the Space Bar.  Nothing seems to activate the links.

Are multiple script links from multiple points not supported in ArcMap 10?  Is there another way to activate these links that I haven't thought of yet?

Comment: As a test, I tried using website URLs.  The "Jump" button worked just fine in this case.  Must be a problem with hyperlinks that use scripts.

Comment: I've the same problem with ArcMap 10.0. When I receive the message that suggest to jump between the hyperlinks I try to click on any of the link and I get the message: "*Unable to open 'C:\dir\foobar.lyr' Please, make sure the path is correct and the document exists*" But if I click on the single layer then the raster load properly. **Note that** if I open the same mxd project into ArcMap 10.2.1 no problem occours and jump function work fine. Have you suggestions?

Comment: So perhaps it is a bug in version 10 that has since been corrected. I know my GIS provider plans to upgrade this year. Hopefully sooner than later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug was fixed installing the Service Pack #5 of ESRI.
The JUMP function works fine in ArcMAP 10.0 with SP5.

Comment: That makes sense. I'm using service pack 3.  Now if only I had control over the updates. Thank you for confirming there is a fix.